# Convert 1d array to multidimensional array in java

Tags: java

Lets say I have 1d array

```
String teams[]={"Michael-Alex-Jessie","Shane-Bryan"};
```

and I want to convert it to multidimensional array which will be like this

```
String group[][]={{Michael,Alex,Jessie},{Shane,Bryan}}.
```

I try to use delimeter but for unknown reason I cannot assign the value of 1d to 2d array. It said incompatible types. Please any help will be much appreciated. Here is my code.

```
String [][]groups ; 
String teams[]={"Michael-Alex-Jessie","Shane-Bryan"};
int a=0,b=0;
String del ="-/"; 

    for (int count = 0; count < teams.length; count++)
    {
       groups[a][b] = teams[count].split(del);
       a++;
    }
```

Comment: You've declared your 2D array, but you haven't initialized it (i.e. `groups = new String[x][y]`) - also, whenever asking a question where you're getting an error message, you want to post the error message as well.

Comment: Yes thanks for reminding me.The error occur at groups[a][b] = teams[count].split(del);When I'm assigning the value of 1d to 2d array and it said incompatible type required java.lang.string found java.lang.string[].

Answer (score 3):

Type of `group[a][b]` is `String` but you are attempting to assign string array (i.e. `String[]`) there.

This is what you really want to do:

```
for (int count = 0; count < teams.length; count++) {
   groups[count] = teams[count].split(del);
}
```

Comment: Do you know any better idea to place them in multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can't assign array of Strings returned by  "teams[count].split(del)" to String

```
public class qq {
String[][] groups;
String teams[] = { "Michael-Alex-Jessie", "Shane-Bryan" };
int a = 0, b = 0;

public void foo() {
    String del = "-/";
    groups = new String[teams.length][];
    for (int count = 0; count < teams.length; count++) {
        groups[count] = teams[count].split(del);
        a++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way where I can place the value in multidimensional array?

Comment: @user1110191 - this algorithm is so silly and primitive so I can't understand what do you mean by saying "better way"

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an array value, not a cell value:

```
   groups[count] = teams[count].split(del);
```

Answer (score 0):

String.split() return an Array of String, not a String